# Compare two strings and find where letter positions match

Tags: vb.net

I want to do a *bitwise* and on two strings so that:

Given:

```
 Dim word As String = "abcd"
 Dim temp As String = "a-d-"
```

I want to return only the 'a'

Given:

```
 Dim word As String = "abcd"
 Dim temp As String = "a--d"
```

I want to return only the 'a--d'

I have tried intersect, but it only finds characters in one string that match the characters in the other regardless of position.

I've used the '-' to represent spaces here.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll have to loop each index of a string, compare the character at that index with the other string and determine if they are equal or not. Can you show what you have tried so we can see what you did wrong?

Comment: One question. In the first sample, you said you only want "a". It that accurate, or do you really want "a---"?

Answer (score 2):

This will handle strings with mis-matched lengths:

```
Public Function CheckMask(ByVal word As String, ByVal mask As String) As String
    Dim wordChars() As Char = word.ToCharArray()
    Dim maskChars() As Char = mask.ToCharArray()

    Dim i As Integer = 0       
    While i < wordChars.Length AndAlso i < maskChars.Length
        If wordChars(i) <> maskChars(i) Then wordChars(i) = " "c
        i = i + 1
    End While

    'If string lengths are equal or the mask is longer, we're done
    'If the word is longer, need to set remaining characters to " "
    While i < wordChars.Length
        wordChars(i) = " "c
    End While

    Return New String(wordChars)
End Function
```

Comment: Is using SB more efficient than &=? I'm not judging, just curious. Or does SB do that in the background?

Comment: @Keith Stringbuilder will create a single character buffer in the background once. &= will allocate and copy a whole new string with each additional append. But forget that: I found an even more efficient way to do this. I knew there was a reason I wanted character arrays :)

Comment: @Jens I found an even better way than the Stringbuilder

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim Res As String = ""    
For i = 0 To Math.Min(StrA.Length, StrB.Length) - 1
    If StrA(i) = StrB(i) Then Res &= StrA(i) Else Res &= " "
Next
Return Res
```

This basically loops to the end of the shorter one of the two strings. If the letters at a given position match the letter is added to the result, else a space is added.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim sFirstWord As String = "qwerty"
    Dim sSecndWord As String = "qseftg"
    Dim sResult As String = ""

    For i As Integer = 0 To Math.Min(sFirstWord.Length, sSecndWord.Length) - 1
        If sFirstWord(i) = sSecndWord(i) Then
            sResult &= sFirstWord(i)
        Else
            sResult &= " "
        End If
    Next
```

sResult will hold: "q e t "